# Change field in all instances of a class using a static field that changes all the instances

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, oop

I've created a user-defined control which is inherited from the `Button` class and I want to make it easy to change the visual style of all the buttons at once, without having to place every instanced control in a collection and having to iterate through them to change specific fields.

#### QUESTION

Can I use a static field to change another, non-static, field in the `base` class of the parent?

Here's a short example:

```
public class KewlButton : Button
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Changes visual properties of the control in all instances at once.
    /// </summary>
    class Crossdress
    {
        static Color BackColor { 
            private get;

            set {
                // Set the BackColor in all instances of KewlButton
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You'd probably have to make some sort of event that all the instances subscribed to.

Comment: Can you code ``KewlButton`` so that it reads the back color from a static property (it doesn't have to be in the same class) when it draws itself? That might do the trick if you can invalidate the whole window when you set the static property, forcing all the buttons to redraw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define some *static event* or *static delegate*, here is for *delegate*:

```
public class KewlButton : Button {
  public delegate void SetBackColor(Color color);
  static SetBackColor setBackColor;
  public KewlButton(){
    setBackColor += ChangeBackColor;
    Disposed += (s,e) => {
       setBackColor -= ChangeBackColor;
    };
  }
  private void ChangeBackColor(Color color){ 
     BackColor = color;
  }
  public class Crossdress {
    public static Color BackColor { 
        set {
            if(setBackColor!=null) setBackColor(value);
        }
    }
  }
}

//Usage
KewlButton.Crossdress.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

The use of *event* is very similar to *delegate*.

Comment: Worked like a charm with a `delegate`. Also, I used `protected` as the access modifier, since I don't want the delegate to be available outside. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve this is to separate out all of the colors you want to control into a completely different class.

```
class MyTheme { 
  public Color BackColor { get; set; } 
  public Color OtherColor { get; set; } 

  public event EventHandler Changed;
}
```

This class would also have an event that was raised in the event any of the values changed.  You could then pass an instance of this type to every Control in your application and have them use it for all of their color access